# Element wise addition of two n dimensional lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, addition

When I need to add two 2D lists element wise, the approach I am using is

```
l1 = [[1, 1, 1],
      [2, 2, 2],
      [3, 3, 3]]

l2 = [[1, 1, 1],
      [2, 2, 2],
      [3, 3, 3]]

new = list(map(lambda e: [sum(x) for x in zip(*e)], zip(l1, l2)))
print(new)
```

```
output : [[2, 2, 2],
          [4, 4, 4],
          [6, 6, 6]]
```

This code is already difficult to read.

So how would I add two n dimensional lists element wise? Is there a pythonic way to do it or should I use numpy?

Comment: The obligatory question: why are you using nested lists? Why are you not using numpy array?

Comment: @Argyll Good question. I was just wondering if there was a way to do it in python that i didn't know about. So numpy is definitely the way to go, i guess.

Comment: numpy is definitely faster. But Python can still cut it - ```[[a+b for a, b in zip(l1, l2)] for l1, l2 in zip(L1, L2)]```  and readable.  Note -L1 is  your l1, L2 ll2.